# Model clouds tablecloth with animation

Tags: fluid-simulation, ocean-simulation

I wanted to create animated clouds to position over a mountain footage.
I want to achieve this effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOpkXBACDU4&t=9s

[image]

How can I do it?

Thank you